# Examples in Test Driven Development By Example by Kent Beck

Tags: oop, tdd, private

I'm reading through [Test Driven Development: By Example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146530) and one of the examples is bugging me. In chapter 3 (Equality for all), the author creates an `equals` function in the `Dollar` class to compare two `Dollar` objects:

```
public boolean equals(Object object)
{
    Dollar dollar= (Dollar) object;
    return amount == dollar.amount;
}
```

Then, in the following chapter (4: Privacy), he makes amount a private member of the dollar class.

```
private int amount;
```

and the tests pass. Shouldn't this cause a compiler error in the `equals` method because while the object can access its own `amount` member as it is restricted from accessing the other `Dollar` object's `amount` member?

```
//shouldn't dollar.amount be no longer accessable?
return amount == dollar.amount
```

Am I fundamentally misunderstanding `private`?

**UPDATE**
I decided to go back and code along with the book manually and when I got to the next part (chapter 6 - Equality For All, Redux) where they push amount into a parent class and make it protected, I'm getting access problems:

```
public class Money
{
    protected int amount;
}

public class Dollar : Money
{
    public Dollar(int amount)
    {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
    // override object.Equals
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Money dollar = (Money)obj;
        //"error CS1540: Cannot access protected member 'Money.amount'
        // via a qualifier of type 'Money'; the qualifier must be of 
        // type 'Dollar' (or derived from it)" on the next line:
        return amount == dollar.amount;
    }
}
```

Does this mean that `protected` IS instance-based in C#?

Comment: I have not read the book, but is it possible that he made a publicly accessible property for the amount member?

Comment: @TheTXI: Java does not have properties. The exact change was that amount used to be package-private field (`int amount;`) and it was changed to be a private field (`private int amount;`). (I don't know why Kent uses package-private in the book instead of public. Maybe it's just to reduce the verbosity of the Java language and to focus on the main points.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, you're fundamentally misunderstanding private.  Privacy is class-specific, not instance-specific.

Comment: Does instance-specific privacy exist?

Comment: Not in any language I'm familiar with.

Comment: In Scala object-private exists. See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826592/dumb-question-about-examples-in-test-driven-development-by-example-by-kent-beck/826638#826638

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally misunderstanding private, Dollar can access any Dollar private method if they are the same class.

Comment: After reading the answers, I'm left wondering: is he fundamentally misunderstanding private?

Answer (score 3):

Modifier private is **class-private**, not object-private.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, `private` means class-private. Within the class, you can access that field in all instances of the class.

In Scala there is also an object-private scope which is written `private[this]`. Also in other respects Scala's scopes are more flexible (see [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-scala07298.html) for more information).

But in Java there is no object-private scope.

Answer (score 2):

In languages of the C++ family (C++,Java,C#), access control is only at the class level. So  `private` allows access to any instance of that class.

IIRC in Smalltalk privacy behaves as you expect.